# basic view activity in android studio error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

hello guys I try to make new project with java in android studio but when I wanna run the project there is some problem with this :::

***4 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.
   [image]

> ```
>   :app is currently compiled against android-33.
> ```

Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdk of at least 34.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).

2. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

> ```
>   :app is currently compiled against android-33.
> ```

Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdk of at least 34.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).

3. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

> ```
>   :app is currently compiled against android-33.
> ```

Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdk of at least 34.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).

4. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

> ```
>   :app is currently compiled against android-33.
> ```

Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdk of at least 34.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).*
**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3xVr.png)
and this is my gradel build ->

> plugins {
> id("com.android.application") }
>
> android {
> namespace = "com.arzju.myapplication"
> compileSdk = 33
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId = "com.arzju.myapplication"
>     minSdk = 24
>     targetSdk = 33
>     versionCode = 1
>     versionName = "1.0"
>
>     testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
> }
>
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         isMinifyEnabled = false
>         proguardFiles(
>             getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
>             "proguard-rules.pro"
>         )
>     }
> }
> compileOptions {
>     sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
>     targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
> }
> buildFeatures {
>     viewBinding = true
> } }
> ```
>
> dependencies {
>
> ```
> implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
> implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
> implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
> implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.0")
> implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.0")
> testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
> androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
> androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
> ```
>
> }

I change the version of some lib and sdk to 34 , 33 for compiling and target but it dosnt work

Comment: Can you also add your Gradle build file.

Comment: I add this you can check it

Comment: Yes so what happens when you update your compileSdk and targetSdk to 34?

Comment: Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
--------I got some thing like this --> duplicate class found

Comment: Looks good to me. What gradle plugin version are you using? Also add your project level gradle file.

Comment: id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false

Comment: I add new data you can see a pic

Comment: Can you try replacing with compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

Answer (score 4):

To solve the error while using basic view Activity in Android Studio, please try the following steps:

In Android Studio right hand side (Top corner find `SDK Manager` click here) and open pop up. Then checkbox checked `Android API level 34` and download it. Then download successfully then finish and `Apply` and `Ok`. After that go to file and search `Invalidate Caches and Restart` then wait. Then rebuild your project and follow this below code:

`build.gradle` file (module app):

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appynitty.navapur_citizen"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled false
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}}
```

`build.gradle` (project_file):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Then in Android Studio, go to file option and select setting. Search `Gradle` and check `JDK` requirement, `JDK11`.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to refrain from using too much bold texts. Or I will be the one to edit it later.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code above defaultConfig

```
 compileSdk = 34
```

Comment: it dosn't work 
Duplicate class found
:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
Igot this error

Comment: is that possible this kind of new project just work for kotlin and not for java ?

Comment: for duplicate classes use turn on jetifier

Answer (score 1):

I just added `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.20"` to my `dependencies` on `build.gradle (:app)` file and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this
add this to build.gradel.kts(:app)

```
 constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

it will be like this :

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

See this [note](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#resolution-of-kotlin-gradle-plugins-transitive-dependencies) in the official kotlin docs for an explanation of how alignment works with these dependencies and build flags. The below original answer is an alternative approach which doesn't take this into account.
The constraints section above can be added in alongside your other dependencies. Choose the version (here 1.8.0) to match the one you actually want to be used, which should be the one that your non-jdkN-named version is in the duplicate class error (e.g. (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0))

Answer (score 0):

I have to do both :

```
compileSdkVersion 34

targetSdkVersion 34
```

And

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

From your `build.gradle.kts`, change this:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

to this:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

Also, from the `Project Structure` set Android Gradle Plugin Version to 8.1.0 and Gradle version to 8.1.

Then go to File -> Settings -> Build tools -> Gradle, set `Gradle JDK` path to:
`jbr-17 JetBrains Runtime version 17.0.6. jbr-17 C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr`

Answer (score 0):

in your project build.gradle file,
upgrade this

id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false

to

id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false

sycn and rebuild.